# JUnit - Java - How to test void method with List of file as parameter

Tags: java, methods, junit, collections, void

I have a class with this method inside:

```
  public class DirectoryWalker {

        public void visitDirectory(String path,List<File> resultList )  {...}
        ...
        }
```

I want to test the method, and I started to do it as showed below.

```
   @Test
        public void ListOfTheFiles(){

       List<File> result = directoryWalker.visitDirectory("pathFile", new ArrayList<File>());
       Assert.assertThat("path\File\\0A54-4444-2441-D554.xml", is(result));
```

To be honest I am little bit confused because this is the first time that I try to test a void method with a list as parameter.

I expect this file:

```
"path\File\\0A54-4444-2441-D554.xml
```

into the folder `File`

Could you help me please? Thanks

EDIT: Of course this istruction is wrong because result is inizialized as List of File:

```
 List<File> result = directoryWalker.visitDirectory(...);
```

All the class:

```
public class DirectoryWalker {

    public void visitDirectory(String path, List<File> resultList ) {

        File root = new File(path);

        File[] list = root.listFiles();

        for (File f : list) {
            if (f.isFile() &&  f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml")) {
                resultList.add(f);
            } else if(f.isDirectory()) {
                visitDirectory(f.getAbsolutePath(),resultList);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Assert.assertThat("path\File\\0A54-4444-2441-D554.xml", is(result));
> ```

You are using the assert in a wrong way.  The patter is:

```
 assertThat([ACTUAL_RESULT], [matcher]([EXPECTED_RESULT]))
```

You doing it the other way around.

Then, if the expected result is a `List`, then why do you compare it to a `String`?

it should be like this:

```
 @Test
    public void ListOfTheFiles(){
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<>();
    directoryWalker.visitDirectory("pathFile", result);
   Assert.assertThat(result, hasItem(new File("path\File\\0A54-4444-2441-D554.xml")));
```

## BTW:

avoid backslashes (`\`) in hardcoded file paths. Use forward slashes (`/`) instead since this ensures compatibility to non windows System which is one major reason to use Java (and not C#)...

Comment: @Timothty Truckle: I am going to try your solution

Comment: @Timothty Truckle: it give me `contains` as error, in red

Comment: @Timothty Truckle: also   `hasItem` for the compiler is an error

Comment: I need to check carefully, but I have now a : java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @StoreCode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47621273/junit-java-how-to-test-void-method-with-list-of-file-as-parameter/47621363?noredirect=1#comment82200985_47621363

Comment: Correct! fixed it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Testing a void method is like testing if what it should done is done properly. You cannot do such thing like result = class.method(...), because this method does not return any value.

What does this method do? It could be helpful...

Comment: the method search and give us the file into the directory. I have upgraded the question with all the class

Comment: IMO Timothy's comment ends discussion ;)